# Persisting checkbox gridview not moving through pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So I made a GridView where I am supposed to keep the values for another module that is already working, but everytime I change the page, the selected values are already forgotten. I built some code, and since I am new to ASP, I dont know, excatly what I did wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    protected void gvApplicants_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvApplicants.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        LoadData();
        Response.Write(gvApplicants.PageIndex.ToString());
        int d = gvApplicants.PageCount;
        bool[] values = new bool[gvApplicants.PageSize];
        CheckBox chb;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gvApplicants.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            chb = (CheckBox)gvApplicants.Rows[i].FindControl("selectedMail");
            if (chb != null)
            {
                values[i] = chb.Checked;
            }
        }
        Session["page" + gvApplicants.PageIndex] = values;
    }

    protected void gvApplicants_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["page" + gvApplicants.PageIndex] != null)
        {
            CheckBox chb;
            bool[] values = (bool[])Session["page" + gvApplicants.PageIndex];
            for (int i = 0; i < gvApplicants.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                chb = (CheckBox)gvApplicants.Rows[i].FindControl("selectedMail");
                chb.Checked = values[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Everytime the index is lost and I cant seem to keep the original one.

Thanks!

Comment: Side-note: you're better off storing the checkbox state values in `ViewState` instead of `Session`. By using `Session` the application will behave unpredictably if users have multiple windows/tabs open on the same page.

Comment: Also your use of `Response.Write` will write data into the output buffer inappropriately (`Response.Write` should only be used inside a Control `Render` method and nowhere else in the page lifecycle) - it may cause an error if code elsewhere decides to write a response header (as headers cannot be modified after the first byte of the response body is sent).

Comment: Thanks for the input. But do you have any insight of what is causing this not to work? This is beyond my poor expertise.

Comment: You want to save/retrieve all the data while moving within pages,right?

Comment: Right, just storing the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built-in paging that comes with GridView then you always have the page index available.  Generally speaking you **never** set the PageIndex in the `PageIndexChanging` event.  `e.NewPageIndex` is what gvApplicants.PageIndex ***will*** be after that event completes, it is there for reference.

Can I infer the following?

1. Each row has a checkbox and I can assume that it's state is not part of your call to `LoadData()`.
2. Each checkbox has AutoPostBack disabled as you are handling save state in the `PageIndexChanging` event.

In order to hold onto the checked state between page changes you need to create a unique id that is held in viewstate that can correctly identify the associated checkbox

---

So in `PageIndexChanging`:

```
protected void gvApplicants_PageIndexChanging( object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e )
{
    GridView gv = (GridView) sender;

    foreach( GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows){
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) gvr.FindControl( "selectedMail" );
        String cbid = String.Format( "cb{0}", gv.PageIndex * gv.PageSize + gvr.RowIndex );

        ViewState[ cbid ] = cb.Checked;
    }
}
```

---

And to restore:

```
protected void gvApplicants_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e )
{
    if ( e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl( "selectedMail" );

        String cbid = String.Format( "cb{0}", gv.PageIndex * gv.PageSize + e.Row.RowIndex );

        cb.Attributes["data-unique-id"] = cbid;
        cb.Checked = ViewState[ cbid ]; 
    }
}
```

---

Please keep in mind that this is very simplistic and messy, not to mention managing line deletions.  But it's better than peppering your session with short term state data.

Consider using a persistable collection accessed from an index property to consolidate the state data. there are plenty of examples on SO.